# PHPMailer - Send Text SMS

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hope everyone is doing good and are safe in times like these.

I am trying to build a sms alert generator. I have 200 phone numbers that I am sending to but I do not know what mobile carrier they belong to.

So far this is what I am doing

```
    // Calculate the length

    $messageLength = strlen(strip_tags($message));
    $numberOfMessages = ceil($messageLength/160);

// Loop through how many messages should be sent (160 character per sms limit)

for($i=0;$i<$numberOfMessages;$i++){
// Add Recipients
    // Calculate the length

    $messageLength = strlen(strip_tags($message));
    $numberOfMessages = ceil($messageLength/160);

// Loop through how many messages should be sent (160 character per sms limit)

for($i=0;$i<$numberOfMessages;$i++){
// Add Recipients

 for($j=0;$j<count($getPhoneListData->myQuery);$j++){
      $phoneNumber1 = str_replace('-','',$getPhoneListData->myQuery[$j]->Phone) . '@vtext.com';
      $phoneNumber2 = str_replace('-','',$getPhoneListData->myQuery[$j]->Phone) . '@txt.att.net';
      $phoneNumber3 = str_replace('-','',$getPhoneListData->myQuery[$j]->Phone) . '@sms.myboostmobile.com';
      $phoneNumber4 = str_replace('-','',$getPhoneListData->myQuery[$j]->Phone) . '@mms.cricketwireless.net';
      $phoneNumber5 = str_replace('-','',$getPhoneListData->myQuery[$j]->Phone) . '@messaging.sprintpcs.com';
      $phoneNumber6 = str_replace('-','',$getPhoneListData->myQuery[$j]->Phone) . '@tmomail.net';

      $mail->AddBCC(trim($phoneNumber1));
      $mail->AddBCC(trim($phoneNumber2));
      $mail->AddBCC(trim($phoneNumber3));
      $mail->AddBCC(trim($phoneNumber4));
      $mail->AddBCC(trim($phoneNumber5));
      $mail->AddBCC(trim($phoneNumber6));
  } 
 }

}
```

Post that, I am sending the message. I keep getting  **Too many recipients** error. What am I doing wrong? What else should I be doing?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding the same phone number multiple times for the same message? It's very likely you have other problems in code you've not shown.

Comment: *Too many recipients*, then do in batches, though your code has 2 numberOfMessages for loops, so for 2 messages 200 recipients, thats 800 emails/sms's maybe you only want to test a single message and reciptant first, get the code working then add it to a loop, unless you dont need your quota/spam rating

Comment: I am adding same phone number multiple times because I do not know what carrier they belong to. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Single recipient works even if added multiple times. I could work on batching it.

Comment: You'll want to use a service which provides the info you need to send sms as email. https://www.data247.com/services/textat for example. They offer an api you can use to get the email address for their carrier based on the phone number you query. They have a monthly fee plus a per lookup charge.